# Django user authentication and login problem

Tags: html, django, django-views, django-templates

I created a signup and signin form. when I create a user using signup it is working perfectly and creates user. but when i try to login with same user it is not able to login. It actually go to else block and show the wrong credential messages.

Whenever I try to login with my existing user it shows wrong credential.

[Error message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ClQDg.png) |
[Users data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OPiZc.png) | [Login window](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Wztj2.png)

view.py

```
    from django.shortcuts import render, HttpResponse, redirect
    from .models import Contact
    from django.contrib import messages
    from blog.models import Post
    from django.contrib.auth.models import User
    from django.contrib.auth import authenticate, login, logout
    
    def handleSignUp(request):
        if request.method == 'POST':
            username = request.POST.get('username')
            fname = request.POST.get('fname')
            lname = request.POST.get('lname')
            email = request.POST.get('email')
            pass1 = request.POST.get('pass1')
            pass2 = request.POST.get('pass2')
    
            #check verify sign field
            if len(username) > 10:
                messages.error(request, 'User name must not more than 10 characters')
                return redirect('/')
            if not username.isalnum():
                messages.error(request, 'User name must contain alpha numeric characters')
                return redirect('/')
            if pass1 != pass2:
                messages.error(request, 'Password did not match')
                return redirect('/')
            #create user
            myuser = User.objects.create_user(username, email, pass1)
            myuser.first_name = fname
            myuser.last_name = lname
            myuser.save()
            messages.success(request, 'You account has been Successfully created')
            return redirect('/')
        else:
            return HttpResponse('404 not found')
    
    def handleLogin(request):
        loginusername = request.POST.get('loginusername')
        loginpassword = request.POST.get('loginpassword')
        user = authenticate(request, username=loginusername, password=loginpassword)
        login(request, user)
        if user is None:
            messages.error(request, 'Wrong Credential, try again')
            return redirect('/')
        else:            
            messages.success(request, 'Your are sucessfully logged in')
            return redirect('/')
        return HttpResponse('handle login')
    def handleLogout(request):
        logout(request)
        messages.success(request, 'Sucessfully Log out')
        return redirect('/')
```

*base.html*

```
            {% if user.is_authenticate %}

            <li class="nav-item dropdown">
                <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" href="#" id="navbarDropdown" role="button" data-toggle="dropdown"
                    aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
                    Welcome {{request.user}}
                </a>
                <div class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="navbarDropdown">
                    <a class="dropdown-item" href="/logout">Logout</a>
                </div>
            </li>
            {% else %}

            <!-- Button trigger for signup modal -->
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-outline-success ml-2" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#signupModal">
                Sign Up
            </button>
            <!-- Button trigger for signup modal -->
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-outline-success ml-2" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#signinModal">
                Sign In
            </button>


            {% endif %}
        </div>
    </nav>
    <!-- this is for messages dissmissal bar -->
    {% for message in messages %}
    <div class="alert alert-{{ message.tags }} alert-dismissible fade show" role="alert">
        <strong>Message: </strong>{{ message }}
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="alert" aria-label="Close">
            <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
        </button>
    </div>
    {% endfor %}
    <!-- ------------------------------------------------- -->
    <!--SignUp  Modal Start From Here -->
    <div class="modal fade" id="signupModal" tabindex="-1" aria-labelledby="signupModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
        <div class="modal-dialog">
            <div class="modal-content">
                <div class="modal-header">
                    <h5 class="modal-title" id="signupModalTitle">Sign Up Here</h5>
                    <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
                        <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
                    </button>
                </div>
                <div class="modal-body">
                    <form action="signup/" method="POST"> {% csrf_token %}
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label for="username">User Name</label>
                            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="username"
                                placeholder="choose unique username (alpha numeric)" name="username" required>
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label for="fname">First Name</label>
                            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="fname" placeholder="First Name" name="fname"
                                required>
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label for="lname">Last Name</label>
                            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="lname" placeholder="Last Name" name="lname"
                                required>
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label for="email">Email address</label>
                            <input type="email" class="form-control" id="email" placeholder="name@example.com"
                                name="email" required>
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label for="pass1">Password</label>
                            <input type="password" class="form-control" id="pass1" name="pass1" required>
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label for="pass2">Re-Enter Password</label>
                            <input type="password" class="form-control" id="pass2" name="pass2" required>
                        </div>
                        <div class="modal-footer">
                            <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
                            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Sign Up</button>
                        </div>
                        {% csrf_token %}
                    </form>
                </div>

            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <!-- ------------------------------------------------- -->
    <!--Sign IN  Modal Start From Here -->
    <div class="modal fade" id="signinModal" tabindex="-1" aria-labelledby="signinModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
        <div class="modal-dialog">
            <div class="modal-content">
                <div class="modal-header">
                    <h5 class="modal-title" id="signinModalTitle">Sign In Here</h5>
                    <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
                        <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
                    </button>
                </div>
                <div class="modal-body">
                    <form action="login/" method="POST">{% csrf_token %}
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label for="loginusername">User Name</label>
                            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="loginusername" placeholder="loginusername
                                name=" loginusername" required>
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label for="loginpassword">Password</label>
                            <input type="password" class="form-control" id="loginpassword" name="loginpassword"
                                required>
                        </div>

                        <div class="modal-footer">
                            <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
                            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Sign In</button>
                        </div>

                    </form>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

    {% block body %}
    {% endblock %}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is [`user.is_authenticated`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/topics/auth/default/#authentication-in-web-requests) not *user.is_authenticate*:

```
{% if user.is_authenticated %}

        <li class="nav-item dropdown">
            <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" href="#" id="navbarDropdown" role="button" data-toggle="dropdown"
                aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
                Welcome {{request.user}}
            </a>
            <div class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="navbarDropdown">
                <a class="dropdown-item" href="/logout">Logout</a>
            </div>
        </li>
{% else %}
```

#### Edit

It seems like you are giving wrong `name` attribute in your HTML. Your name is   `loginusername`, should be `loginusername`. So:

```
 <div class="form-group">
     <label for="loginusername">User Name</label>
     <input name="loginusername" type="text" class="form-control" id="loginusername" placeholder="loginusername" required>
 </div>
```

Comment: still same issue. any other fix?